# Assign collection into an array

Tags: asp.net, arrays, collections

I have a `collection` consists set of items with position ID.
The range of position ID is 500.

For example, this `collection` (retrieve from DB) consists of 3 records as below

```
Name | PositionID
--------------------
ItemA| 3
ItemB| 9
ItemC| 1
```

I have an array with length of 500.

```
int[] arrayPosition = new int[500]
```

And I need to assign each of the item inside the collection into the array according to their PositionID.

```
Array[0] >> ItemC | 1
Array[1] >> null
Array[2] >> ItemA | 3
Array[3] >> null
Array[4] >> null
Array[5] >> null
Array[6] >> null
Array[7] >> null
Array[8] >> ItemB | 9
Array[9] >> null
....
```

My solution is use a `for` loop to read the array and use `foreach` to loop over the entire `collection` and assign them accordingly.

```
for(x=0; x <= Array.Length; x++)
{
    foreach(item in collection)
    ....
}
```

But if let's say the collection consists of 500 items, means the system have to loop 500 * 500 = 250000 times.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a single loop, and use the `PositionID` to determine the index into the array:

```
foreach(item in collection) {
  arrayPosition[item.PositionID - 1] = item;
}
```

(You have declared the array as `int[]`, so it can't hold records from your collection, but this shows the principle of accessing the items in the array using the index.)